# pyflink kafka connector deserializes received json data to null

Tags: json, apache-kafka, apache-flink, stream-processing, pyflink

I am creating a stream processor using PyFlink. When I connect Kafka to Flink, everything works fine. But when I send json data to kafka, PyFlink receives it but the deserialiser converts it to null. PyFlink code is

```
from pyflink.common.serialization import Encoder
from pyflink.datastream.connectors import StreamingFileSink
from pyflink.common.serialization import JsonRowDeserializationSchema
from pyflink.common.typeinfo import Types
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.datastream.connectors import FlinkKafkaConsumer
from pyflink.common import Row


# Starting Flink app
def start_flink_app():
    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
    env.set_parallelism(1)

    env.add_jars(
        "file:///Users/samprabin/Documents/xealei_fall_detector/dataProcessorAndClassifier/jar/flink-sql-connector-kafka_2.11-1.12.3.jar")
    deserialization_schema = JsonRowDeserializationSchema.builder() \
        .type_info(type_info=Types.ROW([Types.INT(), Types.STRING()])).build()



    kafka_consumer = FlinkKafkaConsumer(
        topics='quickstart-events',
        deserialization_schema=deserialization_schema,
        properties={'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:9092', 'group.id': 'test_group'})

    ds = env.add_source(kafka_consumer)
    ds.print()

    env.execute("tutorial_job1")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('Main program started...')
    start_flink_app()
```

And the kafka producer code is

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
from json import dumps

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
                         value_serializer=lambda x: dumps(x).encode('utf-8'))

data = {"name":"tom"}

producer.send('quickstart-events', value=data)
```

please let me know how I can receive the json data in PyFlink

Comment: As a total pyflink noop it seems like your `JsonRowDeserializationSchema` doesn't fit to the data you are sending. You are expecting an INT and a STRING but you are just sending a simple STRING. Maybe this works `{"id" : 1, "name" : "tom"}`

Comment: Hi TobiSH, thank you for your answer. unfortunately, I am still getting "null null"

Comment: can you provide the entire call stack? In which line does the error appear ?

Comment: I am not getting any error. But If I print the data received from the data source I get "null null".  ds = env.add_source(kafka_consumer); ds.print()

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved by using Types.ROW_NAMED instead Types.ROW. Then provide your field names.

```
    deserialization_schema = JsonRowDeserializationSchema.builder().type_info(
                             type_info=Types.ROW_NAMED(
                             ["abc","xyz"], [Types.STRING(), Types.STRING()])).build()
```

Answer (score 0):

i faced same problem. What I did was use to the same serializer/deserializer given in example of  [flink kafka producer](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/python/datastream/intro_to_datastream_api/#emit-results-to-a-datastream-sink-connector) and generate output in a topic. I found that we have to use the following format :

```
{"f0": 123, "f1": "ddd"}
```

and then it works as expected without giving the null null it was giving earlier.